# What can I do about custom emojis in my app?

Tags: android, ios, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app for Windows (Phone, Desktop, Store), Android, iOS and Web which allows user to create emojis. I want to show these emojis between texts with possibly every font (Segoe WP on ios? lol). User will NOT be able to copy these elsewhere, so that's not a problem. However, would making the text part of a html page cause any problems? I think that that might cause html code usage, however, should I use a html page for showing these custom emojis and pictures in the same line, and if so, how can I block user from using html commands? ps. here is a concept art [image: concept art]

Comment: What do you mean by HTML commands?  I know you can turn scripting off in the Browser Controls.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware yes, I can, but wouldn't that block new lines too?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest for windows phone and also a general overview.
(1.) You need to create your emojis images and their relative text code (e.g: smile - ':)' ).
(2.) You need to develop one program that read this codes and convert it to image for each platform in native code.
(3.)you can put images between text easily in windows phone by separating images and text first, after make grammatically Textbox and Image objects and assign them to a StackPanel Container.

```
TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock();
t1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
t1.Text = "this is test ";

TextBlock t2 = new TextBlock();
t2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
t2.Text = " this is test.";

Image img = new Image();
img.Height = img.Height = 20;
img.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icon.png", UriKind.Relative));

sp.Children.Add(t1);
sp.Children.Add(img);
sp.Children.Add(t2);
```

This is just a basic idea how you can implement it. Still you need to take care of new line and height of StackPanel. Ans also fancy design of StackPanel I have used this and it is working for me.

Comment: 1 and 2 is easy :) I know stackpanel but as you said "new line" is a big problem. However, I'll try to fix that.